# Calculating a mean on groupby gives me a "DataError: No numeric types to aggregate"

Tags: python

I'm trying to do some aggregations using groupby

My code looks something like this:

```
 Top15['est_pop'] = Top15['Energy Supply']/Top15['Energy Supply per Capita'] 
 new = Top15.groupby('Continent')['est_pop'].agg({'size': np.size, 'sum': 
                                 np.sum, 'mean': np.mean, 'std': np.std})
```

If I only have Size and sum in my agg, it works fine, but once I add mean or std, it gives me the following error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

I know "est_pop" is a float (and there are no empty values or anything weird like that)

```
type(Top15['est_pop'][(0)])

---> float
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  or what I can do to fix it?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Is est_pop a value, or a `numpy.float64` (or 32)? That may be important for numpy functions like mean and std.

Answer (score 0):

Try:  Top15['est_pop'] =  Top15['est_pop'].astype(float)